# C# windows application crashing suddenly without any error message

Tags: c#, winforms

My application started crashing suddenly without any proper message.

The application was built in ANY CPU and was running on 64 bit machine.

At the time of crash, it was using around `1.5GB` of memory.

The project is storing it all operational process in `SQLCe4.0` as back-end database and the project size was almost around `2.8 GB`.

When I checked Windows event viewer the message was like this :

```
Problem signature: 
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
  Application Name: MyApp.exe 
  Application Version: 2.7.710.1137 
  Application Timestamp: 51dcf6b1 
  **Fault Module Name: StackHash_6bac** 
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0 
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000 
  Exception Code: c0000005 
  Exception Offset: 000000007782000a 
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 
  Locale ID: 1033 
  Additional Information 1: 6bac 
  Additional Information 2: 6bac59273bcf6f09b20009b5873b0c76 
  Additional Information 3: 2600 
  Additional Information 4: 2600c3cc88a8c9bf041ae82fe9962258
```

Read our privacy statement online: 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:

```
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I am unable to figure out what is the exact cause of failure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash / breakpoint your way to the faulty line?

Comment: Provided you have decent error handling in place, that will catch all regular exception it can be one of the "unrecoverable" badass exceptions - StackOverflowException or more likely OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: "I am not able to figure out" What have you tried?

Comment: Is the crash *reproducible*? If so, have you tried attaching a debugger to the running application and then inducing the crash? Can you do so and [edit] your question to include a stack trace?

Comment: You can use debugview to get more details.

Comment: Memory was 1.5GB... How much memory is in the machine? It sounds like quite excessive use of memory. Is there a leak or are you doing something mega?

Comment: in that amount of memory you might have a leak leak there that will crash your system but won't be reproducible

Comment: Hi , the issue is replicated in production environment so currently i cannot attach and debug it , The exception and execution message are stored in project logs. There is no relevant information . System memory is 4 GB. Any one can suggest this point as well "Fault Module Name: StackHash_6bac". What does it mean .

Comment: It does happen repeatedly in production environment?  Is there no way you can copy symbols there, and attach to it?

Comment: You can create an intellitrace file in production and debug on that.

Comment: Google "Fault Module Name StackHash".  You'll read that it means "Windows executive couldn’t identify the module [the app] was in when the application crashed".  Is there any additional Exception handling you can add to your app, to dump more info to log?

Comment: yes it is repeatedly happening but only when the project size is large which i have mentioned earlier. What do you mean by symbols can you tell.

Comment: I mean the standard steps for debugging a production release. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817659.aspx  (by symbols I mean a .pdb file.)  Maybe also a (yourappname.exe.config) file.

Comment: Here are some suggestions re production debugging.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043934/deploying-app-to-production-using-debug-mode-rather-than-release-mode

Comment: Disregard the microsoft link -- that is obsolete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047734/net-debugging-on-production-server  discusses approaches, and mentions some tools.

Answer (score 6):

`Exception Code: c0000005` is a ACCESS_VIOLATION, [that is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2004/06/30/170344.aspx) your program is trying to access region of memory outside it's own. `Fault Module Name: StackHash_6bac` means that [no module was loaded](http://tdistler.com/2009/04/10/stackhash-and-application-crashes-on-windows) on fault address:

> The answer is that the Windows executive couldn’t identify the module
>   we were in when the application crashed (it uses the instruction
>   pointer to determine what code was executing). In this case, the
>   kernel simply takes a hash of the stack so at least we might be able
>   to identify if we’ve seen this exact crash before. Here’s the answer
>   summarized by an engineer from Microsoft:
>
> In the OS when I try to get a faulting module name it is possible that
>   there is no module laoded (sic) at that address. For example in this
>   case the EIP was zero. So in those cases where a module is not loaded
>   and it is not also in the unloaded module list, I take a stack hash of
>   the stack so that we can identify this crash from other crashes where
>   also the module is not known.

Given all that, most probably you are experiencing some resource leak, which eventually leads to this access violation error.

Comment: Hi Petr , Thanks for your information.That may be the case that application if leaking resources but one more things is the same App is running fine in other client environment with almost similar resource .